# bootstrap: Get three thumbnail images inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying multiple ways to get this thing working but nothing seems to work. I want to simply have three thumbnails inline with little bit of space.

For example: username: thumbnailimage1 thumbnailimage1 thumbnailimage1

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="thumbnail">
            <c:if test="${completedRec.goldCompleted > 0}">
                <img src="<c:url value="/img/gold.png"/>"  width="40">
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${completedRec.silverCompleted > 0}">
                <img src="<c:url value="/img/silver.png"/>" width="40">
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${completedRec.bronzeCompleted > 0}">
                <img src="<c:url value="/img/bronze.png"/>" width="40">
            </c:if>                             
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using jsp, where I have a list of information and I iterate over the list to paint the information. I can figure the rest out but I can't seem to get the images inline horizontally. How can I do this in css using bootstrap. I tried thumbnail options and multiple stackoverflow but nothing really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the Boostrap layout:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

The .thumbnail class is only doing formatting (the border, padding); the alignment of the images is actually happening from the .row and the .col-md-3 classes.

It's OK when using Bootstrap to mix your own CSS in with theirs, to handle layouts they don't provide. In this case, here's some CSS which might help:

```
.thumbnails img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

which will work with:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/kg5uewqt/

I've used .thumbnails to avoid conflicting with the Boostrap .thumbnail. Which means you can mix-and-match to get the Boostrap look and feel:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="..." />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="..." />
    <img class="thumbnail" src="..." />
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/kg5uewqt/1/

Comment: if I use the img css you had mentioned will the style get apply to all other img tags I use.

Comment: Yep, you can make the selector more precise to avoid this problem: .thumbnail img { ... }

Comment: so when I use it I do <div class="thumbnail"><img></div>?

Comment: How do i get rid of the borders?

Comment: The border comes from a conflict with bootstrap's own .thumbnail ... I've updated my answer with some better examples to show how to avoid this conflict!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59114/discussion-between-null-hypothesis-and-sifriday).

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple div to get the result you wanted.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
img
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
img
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
img
</div>
</div>
```